# Закладки на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Всем доброго пятничного дня. Как я писал ранее, я изучаю JavaScript по книге Хавербеке.
Одно из заданий звучит так:

---

Интерфейс закладок встречается часто. Он позволяет вам выбирать панель интерфейса, выбирая одну из нескольких торчащих закладок над элементом. В упражнении вам нужно сделать простой интерфейс закладок. Напишите функцию asTabs, которая принимает узел DOM, и создаёт закладочный интерфейс, показывая дочерние элементы этого узла. Ей нужно вставлять список элементов  вверху узла, по одному на каждый дочерний элемент, содержащих текст, полученный из атрибута data-tabname. Все, кроме одного из дочерних элементов, должны быть спрятаны (при помощи display style none), а текущий видимый узел можно выбирать нажатием кнопки. Когда оно заработает, расширьте функционал, чтобы у текущей активной кнопки был свой стиль.

---

В общем на Ваш суд, интересно будет послушать мнение каждого, и профессионала и любителя

```js
function asTabs(node) {
  if (node.nodeType !== 1) return "Not elementNode";
  node.className = "wrapper";
  var divs = Array.prototype.filter.call(node.children, function(elem) {
    return elem.nodeName === "DIV";
  });
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(child, index) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = child.getAttribute("data-tabname");

    if (index !== 0) child.style.display = "none";
    else child.style.display = "";
    button.className = "tab_passive";

    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      var buttonsClassNames = document.getElementsByClassName("tab_active"),
        childrenWrapper = node.children;
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttonsClassNames, function(button) {
        if (button.className === "tab_active") button.className = "tab_passive";
      });
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(childrenWrapper, function(childWrapper) {
        if (childWrapper.style.display === "") childWrapper.style.display = "none";
      });
      child.style.display = "";
      event.target.className = "tab_active";
    });
    document.body.insertBefore(button, node);
  });
  document.getElementsByClassName("tab_passive")[0].className = "tab_active";
}

asTabs(document.querySelector("#wrapper"));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 4px solid firebrick;
  background: lemonchiffon;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tab_active {
  border: 4px solid firebrick;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background: lemonchiffon;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  outline:none;
}

.tab_passive {
  border: 4px solid firebrick;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background: teal;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div data-tabname="one">Закладка один</div>
  <div data-tabname="two">Закладка два</div>
  <div data-tabname="three">Закладка три</div>
</div>
```

[image: Та самая непонятная белая линия]

Вот как вариант исправленных, только стили надо переделывать

```
function asTabs(node) {
    if(node.nodeType!==1) return "Not elementNode";
    node.className = "wrapper";

    var elementsTab = Array.prototype.filter.call(node.children,function(elem){
        if(elem.getAttribute("data-tabname")) return elem.nodeName;
        else elem.innerHTML = "";
    });

    var bookmarks = document.createElement("div");
    bookmarks.className = "bookmarks";
    node.insertBefore(bookmarks, node.firstElementChild);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsTab, function(child,index){
        var bookmark = document.createElement("button");
        bookmark.textContent = child.getAttribute("data-tabname");
        if(index!==0) child.style.display = "none";
        else child.style.display = "";
        bookmark.className = "tab_passive";
        bookmark.addEventListener("click",function(event){
            var bookmarkClassNames = node.getElementsByClassName("tab_active");
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(bookmarkClassNames,function(button){button.className="tab_passive"});
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsTab,function(childWrapper){childWrapper.style.display = "none"});
            child.style.display = "";
            event.target.className = "tab_active";
        });
        bookmarks.appendChild(bookmark);
    });
    node.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.className="tab_active";
}
```

Но теперь до меня дошло, что я не понимаю откуда событие "помнит" что такое node и что такое child

Comment: добавь пример разметки, в идеале, сделай  [сниппет](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999) чтобы можно было сразу увидеть как у тебя работает код

Comment: окей, щас разберусь как его сделать и будет

Comment: в чем смысл фильтрации дивов? и самой первой проверки _node.nodeType!==1_? ничего не вижу в задании про это

Comment: почему кнопки вставляются перед выбранным элементом? Судя по заданию: _нужно вставлять список элементов **вверху узла**_ вставлять нужно внутрь переданного элемента

Comment: По поводу проверки и фильтрации - отсебятина, честно. А вставка кнопок перед узлом, потому что не нравилось как выглядело

Comment: Только вот не понимаю откуда берется пробел между кнопками и формой вывода. В виде тонкой белой линии. Что интересно, при увеличении масштаба страницы - она пропадает

Comment: у меня нет линии

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54731/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: прикрепил изображение в сам пост(тему)

Comment: У вас тут код ревью? Или в чём вопрос?

Comment: Да, это код ревью